# Is there a way to have latex detect forward references?

Tags: cross-referencing

I've got a very large document (which I've broken into "chapters" and such) which I've recently moved a few things around in.  Is there a nice way to get latex to output a list of forward references? (like, things in chapter 5 that reference a result in chapter 10)

Answer (score 16):

Here's a way to write out all of your references, forward, backward, and undefined to `\jobname.refs`.

```
\newwrite\refs
\openout\refs=\jobname.refs
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\@setref[3]{%
        \ifx#1\relax
                \write\refs{'#3' \thepage\space undefined}%
                \protect \G@refundefinedtrue
                \nfss@text{\reset@font\bfseries ??}%
                \@latex@warning{Reference `#3' on page \thepage\space
                                undefined}%
        \else
                \write\refs{'#3' \thepage\space
                            \expandafter\@secondoftwo#1}%
                \expandafter#2#1\null
        \fi
}
\makeatother
```

LaTeX doesn't keep track of chapter, so this writes out pages instead. The format is

```
'ref name' page refpage
```

You could easily change the `\else` case to do the `\write\refs` only if the second number was later than the first. Basically, change the `\else` clause to the following.

```
                \begingroup
                \count@\expandafter\@secondoftwo#1\relax
                \ifnum\c@page<\count@
                        \write\refs{'#3' \thepage\space
                                    \expandafter\@secondoftwo#1}%
                \fi
                \endgroup
                \expandafter#2#1\null
```

Comment: This reminds me: one of the things I've always wanted to do is write a list of undefined or duplicate references at the end of the console output. Some day! (P.S. Great answer.)

Comment: Great answer! Just for those not familiar with `\makeatletter`, could you please add `\makeatother` at the end of your code?

Comment: How would one adjust this to work when the referencing command is \autoref from the hyperref package?

Comment: Rookie here, where do I "run" this, or am I just adding this to my document - if so where does it save it? So far I was just able to get an empty .refs file.

Comment: @mrk: the code should be added to the preamble of your document. If you tex file has name `myfile.tex`, then the output would be in `myfile.refs`. If it doesn't work: please ask a new question and link to this one.

Comment: @Chris: if I were you I would probably just comment out `\usepackage{hyperref}`, and `\let\autoref\ref` and run the code above to generate the reference list. And then undo the source modification to build your real document. (The way `hyperref` is written, you will have to search through `hyperref.sty` and apply the same patch to every command that looks like `\HyRef@<something>setref`.)

Answer (score 7):

TH. already gave a nice answer (I would even say that that is the way *it ought to be done*). But here a technologically cheap way since you've already broken it up in terms of chapters:

1. Remove all `.aux` files
2. `\includeonly{chapter1}` and compile. See if there are broken references. Then
3. `\includeonly{chapter2}` and compile. See if there are broken references.
4. Rinse and repeat.

Comment: I thought the point of `\includeonly` was that it worked correctly with references.

Comment: @TH Yes, but only if the .aux files are present: you have to `\includeonly{chapterN}` each chapter at least once in order to produce the chapterN.aux file, so Willie's recipe should indeed work. But your answer still is better in my opinion.

Comment: @Lev Bishop: Ah, okay. I've never actually used `\includeonly`.

Comment: Of course, TH.'s answer is much better. In my answer above, I counted on `\includeonly` working with references already present in .aux files to only show broken forward references and not working backward references. This is just the sort of cheap thing one can put together at one in the morning without thinking too hard.